# Plot two datasets at same position based on their index

Tags: python, matplotlib, plot

I'm trying to plot two datasets (called `Height` and `Temperature`) on different y axes.

Both datasets have the same length.

Both datasets are linked together by a third dataset, `RH`.

I have tried to use matplotlib to plot the data using `twiny()` but I am struggling to align both datasets together on the same plot.

Here is the plot I want to align.

[image]

The horizontal black line on the figure is defined as the 0°C degree line that was found from `Height` and was used to test if both datasets, when plotted, would be aligned. They do not. There is a noticable difference between the black line and the 0°C tick from `Temperature`.

Rather than the two y axes changing independently from each other I would like to plot each index from `Height` and `Temperature` at the same y position on the plot.

Here is the code that I used to create the plot:

```
#Define number of subplots sharing y axis
f, ax1 = plt.subplots()

ax1.minorticks_on()
ax1.grid(which='major',axis='both',c='grey')

#Set axis parameters
ax1.set_ylabel('Height $(km)$')
ax1.set_ylim([np.nanmin(Height), np.nanmax(Height)])

#Plot RH
ax1.plot(RH, Height, label='Original', lw=0.5)

ax1.set_xlabel('RH $(\%)$')

ax2 = ax1.twinx()

ax2.plot(RH, Temperature, label='Original', lw=0.5, c='black')

ax2.set_ylabel('Temperature ($^\circ$C)')

ax2.set_ylim([np.nanmin(Temperature), np.nanmax(Temperature)])
```

Any help on this would be amazing. Thanks.

Comment: First of all just for readability: you can do `f, ax = plt.subplots()` and consequently leave indexing of `ax` completely away if only one plot is needed. `sharey` is not needed at all, because it adresses the several y axes of more than one subplot. And `squeeze` is meaningless then, too...

Comment: I'm a bit confused about what `dataset1` and `dataset2` are. You seem to have multiple datasets and nothing in the code is named `dataset1` or `dataset2`.

Comment: I agree, without a hint what are dependant and what independant data, it's hard to understand or even guess what's going on here.

Comment: I've updated the question with your comments to make things hopefully clearer. I want to plot `Height` and `Temperature` at the same position on the plot, aligning each index together

Comment: can you add some sample data

Answer (score 1):

Maybe the atmosphere is wrong.  :)

It sounds like you are trying to align the two y axes at particular values.  Why are you doing this?  The relationship of Height vs. Temperature is non-linear, so I think you are setting the stage for a confusing graph.  Any particular line you plot can only be interpreted against one vertical axis.

If needed,  I think you will be forced to "do some math" on the limits of the y axes.  This link may be helpful:

[align scales](https://code.i-harness.com/en/q/9ff146)

Comment: Haha, yes the atmosphere is most likely wrong! The measurements of Height, RH and Temperature were taken on board a radiosonde. For the same index in Height, RH and Temperature were measured at the same time. I wanted them to be plotted at the same position on the graph. i.e. when the temperature was measured 0°C the RH and Height would match correctly.

Comment: I kind of figured that.  Your graph will be tough to interpret.  Height is your independent variable and it naturally fits on the vertical axis.  RH and TEMP both depend on height and should both be horizontal, I think.  I would make 2 side-by-side plots with subplots, put temp on vertical axis and set `sharey=True`